# Changing dateformat of a column and creating a new column based on other column

Tags: mysql, date-format

I have a column "date" and its format (Y-m-d -time). I need to create a new column using a SQL query and it will be the same with "date" column but it's format will be (Y-m-d) only not with hours etc.

And I want to group them with GROUP BY. How can I write this query? I have to create a temporary column to see them grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **[`DATE_FORMAT`](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(columnName, '%Y-%m-%d')
```